# Jquery fails when i use button tag in HTML to call Javascript function which in turn uses Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have button on my HTML page. Initially i was using

```
<input name="op" id="changepass_submit" value="Change Password" disabled="disabled" class="form-submit" type="button" onClick="change_passwd();" />.
```

Using this i am able to call the javascript function change_passwd() which has it's definition as,

```
function change_passwd()
{
    var o_pass = document.getElementById('o_passwd').value;
    var n_pass = document.getElementById('n_passwd').value;
    var c_pass = document.getElementById('c_passwd').value;
    if(n_pass == "")
        alert("New Password can not be empty!");
    else 
    {
        if(n_pass == o_pass)
        {
            alert('New password and old password are same! Please choose different new password.');
        }
        else
        {
            o_pass = rtrim(ltrim(o_pass));
            n_pass = rtrim(ltrim(n_pass));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {o_pass:o_pass,n_pass:n_pass},
                url: "changepass",
                success: function(response) {
                    var result = eval(response);
                    alert(result[1]);
                    window.location = "/my_profile";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine.

But when i change `<input>` tag to:

```
<button name="op" id="changepass_submit" disabled="disabled" class="form-submit" onClick="change_passwd();" style="width:150px;"><strong>Change Password</strong></button>
```

it gives jQuery error..

why so? If any body has any suggestions or answers pls let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question really doesn't make any sense. Specifically, what does, "change tag to **Change Password** " mean?  Change **what** tag?  Where?

Comment: Edited the question formatting so it does make more sense! But post the jQuery error you get too.

Comment: just forget the disabled attribute of the input and button element because i am changing its value in the middle.

Comment: @aashish what's the error?  Also sorry I didn't guess that it was a Markdown problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the jQuery error (what's the error?) but a `<button>` is `type="submit"` by default and not `type="button"`. That means when clicked (assuming it is not disabled as in the markup), since you do not `return false` to cancel the default action, the form will continue to submit, potentially cancelling your `ajax()` operation.

Comment: He's got `type="button"` way down on the far end of the opening tag.

Comment: i don't have any form in the HTML page. Still it can give this error ?

Comment: It worked when i put attribute type="button" in <button> tag. ty bobince. I have one question when we are specifying that the tag is button why to give type="button" ??

Comment: @bobince **oh** now I see - he went from `<input>` to `<button>`.  Boy I'm pretty slow sometimes.

Comment: `<button>` can replace three types of button: actionless `button`, a form `submit` or a `reset`. So it's necessary to state which you mean. I guess `submit` was chosen because `button` on its own does nothing, requiring JavaScript intervention, so `submit` was seen as the more likely case. (IE didn't agree, defaulting to `button` instead, so omitting `type` is unreliable.) Incidentally you don't necessarily need to use a `<button>` if all you want is bold text; a plain `input` with CSS `font-weight` can do that.